# How to add a Firebug Lite extension to Internet Explorer 7/8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, toolbar, ieaddon, firebug-lite

I've been trying to figure out how [BrowserStack has added Firebug Lite](http://www.browserstack.com/debugging-tools) as an extension to IE 7/8 but cannot seem to find anything that does this. See the image below and note how Firebug icon appears as button in the toolbar.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I know how to add it to my Favorites, but I want the icon to appear in the toolbar along with the other buttons (by going to Tools -> Customize Toolbar)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Browser Helper Object. The development steps are to [add the icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753591), [bind the click event to the browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms976373#bho_getintouch), and [inject the script content](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w).

**References**

- [Mozilla ActiveX Control](http://people.mozilla.org/~chofmann/l10n/tree/mozilla/embedding/browser/activex/src/control/MozillaBrowser.cpp)
- [Chrome Frame ActiveX Control](http://src.chromium.org/svn/releases/4.0.259.0/src/chrome_frame/chrome_frame_activex.cc)
- [Browsium Catalyst FAQ](http://www.browsium.com/catalyst/faqs/)
- [Measure Page Load Time BHO](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/tools/measure_page_load_time/ie_bho/MeasurePageLoadTimeBHO.cpp)
- [Button Demo BHO](http://code.google.com/p/pricegoblin/source/browse/trunk/ButtonDemo/ButtonDemoBHO.cpp)
- [Building Browser Helper Objects with Visual Studio 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489)
- [Customizing Internet Explorer with User Stylesheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158570.aspx)